# Collect disk space metrics for whole SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, disk-space

I am quite new to SQL Server. I would like to collect database disk space metrics for the SQL Server instance as a whole.

I have found a code sample that can collect disk space information *per database*.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DISK.dbo.disk_activity') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE disk_activity

CREATE TABLE disk_activity (
       servername NVARCHAR(100)
    ,  database_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    , name NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , data_used_size DECIMAL(18,2)
    , log_used_size DECIMAL(18,2)
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    USE [' + d.name + ']
    INSERT INTO DISK.dbo.disk_activity (servername, database_id, name, data_used_size, log_used_size)
    SELECT
          (SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS "Server Name") AS SERVER_NAME
        , DB_ID()
        , DB_NAME()
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN space_used END)
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN space_used END)
    FROM (
        SELECT s.[type], space_used = SUM(FILEPROPERTY(s.name, ''SpaceUsed'') * 8. / 1024)
        FROM sys.database_files s
        GROUP BY s.[type]
    ) t;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

However, I would like to collect the metrics across the entire server, i.e. total disk space allocated for all databases, total disk space used, total disk space free, and percentage of disk space used.

How should I modify the above script or are there other options available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To monitor disk space usage and database file size I use [this script that you can find on my blog](https://spaghettidba.com/2014/09/05/database-free-space-monitoring-the-right-way/):

```
-- create a temporary table to hold data from sys.master_files
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#masterfiles') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #masterfiles;

CREATE TABLE #masterfiles (
    database_id int,
    type_desc varchar(10),
    name sysname,
    physical_name varchar(255),
    size_mb int,
    max_size_mb int,
    growth int,
    is_percent_growth bit,
    data_space_id int,
    data_space_name nvarchar(128) NULL,
    drive nvarchar(512),
    mbfree int
);

-- extract file information from sys.master_files
-- and correlate each file to its logical volume
INSERT INTO #masterfiles
SELECT
     mf.database_id
    ,type_desc
    ,name
    ,physical_name
    ,size_mb = size / 128
    ,max_size_mb =
        CASE
            WHEN max_size = 268435456 AND type_desc = 'LOG' THEN -1
            ELSE
                CASE
                    WHEN max_size = -1 THEN -1
                    ELSE max_size / 128
                END
        END
    ,mf.growth
    ,mf.is_percent_growth
    ,mf.data_space_id
    ,NULL
    ,d.volume_mount_point
    ,d.available_bytes / 1024 / 1024
FROM sys.master_files AS mf
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(database_id, file_id) AS d;

-- add an "emptyspace" column to hold empty space for each file
ALTER TABLE #masterfiles ADD emptyspace_mb int NULL;

-- iterate through all databases to calculate empty space for its files
DECLARE @name sysname;

DECLARE c CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY STATIC LOCAL
FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max)
    SET @sql = '
        UPDATE mf
        SET emptyspace_mb = size_mb - FILEPROPERTY(name,''SpaceUsed'') / 128,
            data_space_name =
                ISNULL(
                    (SELECT name FROM sys.data_spaces WHERE data_space_id = mf.data_space_id),
                    ''LOG''
                )
        FROM #masterfiles AS mf
        WHERE database_id = DB_ID();
    '
    SET @statement = 'EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(@name) + '.sys.sp_executesql @sql'
    EXEC sp_executesql @statement, N'@sql nvarchar(max)', @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @name
END

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c

-- create a scalar function to simulate the growth of the database in the drive's available space
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..calculateAvailableSpace') IS NOT NULL
    EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_executesql N'DROP FUNCTION calculateAvailableSpace'

EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_executesql N'
CREATE FUNCTION calculateAvailableSpace(
    @diskFreeSpaceMB float,
    @currentSizeMB float,
    @growth float,
    @is_percent_growth bit
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    IF @currentSizeMB = 0
        SET @currentSizeMB = 1
    DECLARE @returnValue int = 0
    IF @is_percent_growth = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @returnValue = (@growth /128) * CAST((@diskFreeSpaceMB / (@growth / 128)) AS int)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @prevsize AS float = 0
        DECLARE @calcsize AS float = @currentSizeMB
        WHILE @calcsize < @diskFreeSpaceMB
        BEGIN
            SET @prevsize = @calcsize
            SET @calcsize = @calcsize + @calcsize * @growth / 100.0
        END
        SET @returnValue = @prevsize - @currentSizeMB
        IF @returnValue < 0
            SET @returnValue = 0
    END

    RETURN @returnValue
END
'

-- report database filegroups with less than 20% available space
;WITH masterfiles AS (
    SELECT *
        ,available_space =
            CASE mf.max_size_mb
                WHEN -1 THEN tempdb.dbo.calculateAvailableSpace(mbfree, size_mb, growth, is_percent_growth)
                ELSE max_size_mb - size_mb
            END
            + emptyspace_mb
    FROM #masterfiles AS mf
),
spaces AS (
    SELECT
         DB_NAME(database_id) AS database_name
        ,data_space_name
        ,type_desc
        ,SUM(size_mb) AS size_mb
        ,SUM(available_space) AS available_space_mb
        ,SUM(available_space) * 100 /
            CASE SUM(size_mb)
                WHEN 0 THEN 1
                ELSE SUM(size_mb)
            END AS available_space_percent
    FROM masterfiles
    GROUP BY DB_NAME(database_id)
        ,data_space_name
        ,type_desc
)
SELECT *
FROM spaces
WHERE available_space_percent < 20
ORDER BY available_space_percent ASC

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#masterfiles') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #masterfiles;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..calculateAvailableSpace') IS NOT NULL
    EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_executesql N'DROP FUNCTION calculateAvailableSpace'
```

Basically, it uses `sys.master_files` to query the size of all the database files and `sys.dm_os_volume_stats` to query the drive info. `FILEPROPERTY` returns information on the available space inside the file.

The script there was meant for alerting when available free space falls under a threshold (say 20%), but it can be modified to perform regular monitoring and record the information in a centralized table.

Don't overlook what the [Data Collector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677179.aspx) feature can record in the Management Data Warehouse database. The feature is available in all editions of SQL Server (express excluded for the lack of an agent to schedule the collection). If the reports you have there are not enough, you could query the tables directly (you just need to query `[snapshots].[disk_usage]` in the MDW database).

In particular, if you're on Enterprise Edition, the [Utility Control Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210548.aspx) feature focuses on resource utilization with a "holistic" approach. Again, it provides some reports and a dashboard to see resource utilization across the whole server infrastructure or the single server.

In my experience, Data Collector and Utility Control Point are the most underused features in SQL Server.

Answer (score -2):

Read up on the Performance Data Warehouse feature. Gives you space metrics and a LOT more (that sooner or later you or someone doing operations will like to have available) and is actually part of the product.

Comment: **Management** Data Warehouse still doesn't show you the total size